# How create a column lecture in Android app

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I'm thinking about create an app to read news, with lecture in columns like Google Currents or Poket in Android with flipping text. How I can do this think? With a webview with the flipping lógic in javascript? A webview with N css-columns and the flipping lógic in a custom webview? A big textview and changing the text dinamically? Another option?